# Download file Server Error: The handle is invalid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, iis-7, file-access

```
   public ActionResult FileLink(string hashname)
    {
        try
        {
            const string basePath = @"\\WINDHOVERDOCUMENTS\";
            const string adminSamples = @"Beta\students\";

            return File(basePath + adminSamples + hashname, "application/force-download", hashname);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null; //no file
        }
    }
```

This action simple force user to download the file when the action is triggered. Everything works fine locally. But after publishing to server, it gives me this error. Below is the screenshot. Can anyone help? Thank you. please zoom in to see the screenshot. Sorry.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I solved that by reading the file to byte array then return file content result

```
            var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\path\fileP12.zip");
            return File(fileBytes, "application/zip", "package.zip");
```